# Is there a "repair connection" equivalent in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

The problem:

- In my laptop I lose wifi connectivity occasionally.
- In Windows XP, the solution to fix my wifi connection is to right click on the taskbar wifi icon and click "repair connection".
- I just upgraded to Windows 7... and I still lose the wifi connection.

The question:

In Windows 7 I can't find anything like "Windows XP's 'repair connection'". **Is there a one-click "repair connection" in Windows 7? If yes how do I reach it?**

**If no, what is equivalent to the windows XP "repair connection"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 7 here's what I found to be similar to "Windows XP 'repair connection'":

- Goto: Control Panel --> Network and Sharing Center --> Change Adapter Settings
- Right click: Your "Wireless Network Connection"
- Click: "Disable"
- Click: "Enable"

**Summary: In Windows 7 Enable/Display the wireless network adapter to "repair the connection".**

---

(

p.s.

Windows 7's "Troubleshoot connection" is not similar to "Windows XP's repair connection":

I saw on google that you can right click the wifi taskbar icon and click "troubleshoot" but ... I exhaustively explored and could not get "troubleshoot" to reestablish the wifi connection.

)

Comment: There's no option to enable over a wifi adapter is disabled. Hit diagnose and sometimes this fails so click diagnose as admin. It seems like sometimes you have to diagnose a few times before it works.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to have a problem with your laptop disconnecting from the wireless (unless it is your laptop's hardware or wireless interference or bad router), I suggest to check your laptop's BIOS and update it, also download the latest Wireless Network Card Drivers.

Answer (score 0):

At anytime, you can rightclick the network icon and click troubleshoot connection.

Repeated drops point to a deeper sign.

Actually, the Windows 7 troubleshoot connection is **more** than the XP repair connection. It is built on a platform called Troubleshooting packs. It will try numerous options **including disabling and enabling the adapter.**

Comment: I clicked "troubleshoot" but I was not able to get my connection restored using this feature. Any tips?